# Regular expression to make it universal to read stream from SQL database:

Tags: c#, database, xamarin

I have columns in SQL database:[description], user can input comma when input text for item description but my regular expression does not recognize, show not support...below my reg expression request in c#:

```
if (content.ToString().IndexOf("Asset found.") > 0)
{
    string[] txt = content.ToString().Split('{');
    txt = txt[2].ToString().Split(',');

    MyGlobalVal.ASSET_DESCRIPTION = txt[0].ToString().Split(':')[1].Substring(1, txt[0].ToString().Split(':')[1].Length-2);
    MyGlobalVal.ASSET_LABEL = txt[1].ToString().Split(':')[1].Substring(1, txt[1].ToString().Split(':')[1].Length-2);
    MyGlobalVal.ASSET_TYPE = txt[2].ToString().Split(':')[1].Substring(1, txt[2].ToString().Split(':')[1].Length-2);
    MyGlobalVal.EPC = txt[7].ToString().Split(':')[1].Substring(1, txt[7].ToString().Split(':')[1].Length-2);
    MyGlobalVal.FID = txt[8].ToString().Split(':')[1].Substring(1, txt[8].ToString().Split(':')[1].Length-2);
    MyGlobalVal.ROOM_CODE = txt[11].ToString().Split(':')[1].Substring(1, txt[11].ToString().Split(':')[1].Length-2);
    MyGlobalVal.TID = txt[14].ToString().Split(':')[1].Substring(1, txt[14].ToString().Split(':')[1].Length-4);

    var Save_tid_fid = new Intent(mContext, typeof(Save_tid_fid));
    StartActivity(Save_tid_fid);
```

I would like to read any kind of text written in [Descripton] column in SQL database into Device: I mean: text with comma, etc.

Comment: oh no, please try to simplify your code first, seems to be very messy. Too many `substring` and `split`

Comment: And those 15 `.ToString()` are not needed as `txt` is an array of strings, thus when referencing an index, you already have a string.

Comment: so you are actually trying to parse a json string. Use a [json deserielizer](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm). Life will be a lot more easy

Comment: else
                        {
                            MyGlobalVal.ASSET_DESCRIPTION = "";
                            MyGlobalVal.ASSET_LABEL = "";
                            MyGlobalVal.ASSET_TYPE = "";
                            MyGlobalVal.EPC = "";
                            MyGlobalVal.FID = "";
                            MyGlobalVal.ROOM_CODE = "";
                            MyGlobalVal.TID = "";
                            var check_fid = new Intent(mContext, typeof(check_fid));
                            StartActivity(check_fid);
                        }

Comment: it is the continuous of that code..sorry..

Comment: using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                // web service 
                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    Console.Out.WriteLine("Error fetching data. Server returned status code: {0}", response.StatusCode);
                }
                else
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        var content = reader.ReadToEnd();

Comment: above goes first... then regular..  I expected to diminish that code into another parsing simple code which is to universal: read any text with commas, etc..from sql database.. expected result but ...

Comment: it is messy guys)) with all possibilities I want to find a some solution. Mr. Manish, I will try to understand the json deserializer. Thnx